# How can i interpret this : sprintf(var_ptr_char+strlen(var_ptr_char).... C code

Tags: c, printf, buffer, strcat, string.h

how could i interpret this : **var_ptr_char+strlen(var_ptr_char)**
in the follow piece of C code :

```
#define INT_CONSTANT 80
char var_ptr_char[1024];
strcat(var_ptr_char,"SOMETHING");
sprintf(var_ptr_char+strlen(var_ptr_char),":%d",INT_CONSTANT);
```

and how much size will I put in order to change sprintf by snprintf.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this the real code? It's undefined behavior. If you don't know that, I suggest reading about what [tag:c-strings] are and how `strcat()` works, and what does `sprintf()` .

Comment: `sprintf(var_ptr_char, "%s:%d", "SOMETHING", INT_CONSTANT);` instead of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument of `sprintf` is a `char` pointer (i.e a `char` buffer.) The function will "print" at that buffer and will start at the position pointed to by the pointer.

Adding *N* to a pointer, means pointing to the N-th position. Therefore, if we add `strlen(var_ptr_char)` to `var_ptr_char`, we're effectively passing the pointer to the last character of the buffer (assuming it did already contain a valid string).

The `snprintf` call, could then be like this:

```
snprintf(var_ptr_char + strlen(var_ptr_char), 1024 - strlen(var_ptr_char) - 1, ":%d", INT_CONSTANT);
```

**TL;DR:** It appends the string to the end of the already stored string in `var_ptr_char`.

Comment: Note that `var_ptr_char` does not certainly contain a string in this case.

Comment: Right, it might not. However by the looks of the code excerpt (which seems an incomplete collection of lines), I'd assume that `var_ptr_char` might already contain a valid string of arbitrary length, ending in `SOMETHING` before the `sprintf` call.